# AWS AMI Unable to look up root device name for image 'null'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to upgrade my Beanstalk application from running on T2.small to T3a.small servers, but it throws an error saying "Unable to look up root device name for image 'null'." under the AMI ID section.

Upgrading to T2.medium works fine. Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

**Elastic Beanstalk supports new instance types soon after Amazon EC2 introduces them, typically by the next platform update.**

`T3/M5/C5` are few of the new compute instance types. You most probably using older platform version. You have to upgrade your platform to use new instance types.

You can read more about at [Your Elastic Beanstalk environment's Amazon EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html)